# Can I run c++ compiled exe in any any other pc?

Tags: c++, windows, exe, desktop-application

I have made a game in c++ and now I want to share that game with my friends. So, I shared that compiled exe file with my friend, but it gives him errors like - crashing and dll errors.

So, how he can run that exe file successfully without downloading mingw/compiler?

**I have used these libraries :-**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

I tried run compiled c++ exe file to run in **another pc.**

I am expecting that it should **successfully** run without any errors.

Comment: lets solve one by one "crashing and dll errors". 1st `dll errors` lets try to install needed dll libs in the pc. 2nd `crash` => use debug tool like gdb to investigate the bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you link your libraries *statically*, it should run fine, provided it's a compatible OS/environment. If your libraries are linked *dynamically*, then during the *runtime* of the application, your libraries should be present in the form of DLL files.

Here it seems like you're dynamically linking the C++ runtime, and that is causing the issue. Either have your friend install the appropriate runtime environment, or link it statically.

Comment: No, my friend don't have appropriate runtime environment as does not have g++ installed.  Can you tell me that how I can link the libraries statically.

Comment: The flag should be "-static-libstdc++". Google it to be safe.